# Runtime Error -- Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT -- No Console Output

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sigabrt

First off, I realize there are a thousand questions with this subject, but I looked through many of them and could not find a solution.

I'm working on a simple tutorial from developer.apple.com. I have followed it step by step.

When I run the project, it compiles fine, but about 1 out of every 3 or 4 times the following happens:

[image]

As you can see I get no output in the console so I'm at a loss (99% of the other posts on this subject come with some sort of meaningful output). This EXACT same this was happening on the previous tutorial I worked on. I fixed it by deleting all localization files and turning off localization. Localization is not enabled on this project.

The connections for the IBOutlets are all fine. I tried adding an exception breakpoint, it doesn't trip.

I can post more information (source code, threads, etc), but I wanted to get a general feel as to whether or not it would even be valuable for the experts. The fact that there is no output might make it obvious. Let me know.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Enable a universal break point thrown on exception and see if it takes you to the line. Also press play in the debug u can see the error message. This doesn't say much right now. We need to see the debug error in the console.

Comment: When I press play it switches to the simulator and goes to the home screen. Xcode drops out of debug mode. I've added an "exception breakpoint" which doesn't trip. What's a universal break point? Yes, I would love to see the debug error too!! Is there some feature of xcode that needs to be turned on? I'm using the "out of box" settings.

Comment: Are you using OS X 10.8.4? If so, there is a bug in that update that affects the simulator. Use Edit Scheme and switch the debugger from LLDB to GDB.

Comment: On the menu on the left second button from the right is the breakpoint navigator. Press + at the bottom and click add breakpoint on exception throw

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely the simulator by in 10.8.4.  Drag the slider all the way to the right, and you'll see some nonsense about "registering purple ports."

Comment: waf - As I mentioned, I already did this--will not trip. Yes, I am using OS X 10.8.4. And yes, when I drag the slider to the right, I do see "GSRegisterPurpleNamedPort". OK-I will switch the debugger from LLDB to GDB. Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't think I was doing anything wrong!

Comment: In GDB now I am getting a console output. It is picking up something on the Exception Breakpoint: 
Catchpoint 2 (throw)Pending breakpoint 1 - "objc_exception_throw" resolved

Comment: @EvanMulawski how do you know this is a bug? Is there a bug report?

Comment: @maq: Yes: http://openradar.appspot.com/14085131 and http://www.tuaw.com/2013/06/05/devjuice-10-8-4-and-the-ios-simulator/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by Evan Mulawski and CodaFi in comments, this is a known bug:

Are you using OS X 10.8.4? If so, there is a bug in that update that affects the simulator. Use Edit Scheme and switch the debugger from LLDB to GDB.

http://www.tuaw.com/2013/06/05/devjuice-10-8-4-and-the-ios-simulator/